# Какие технологии применить - архитектура ленты событий?

Tags: проектирование, php, архитектура, nosql, mongodb

Планируется создание ленты событий как в VK. Лента формируется исходя из подписок пользователей. Например подписаться на пользователя или на новости.
Какие технологии применить? Mysql решение отпадает сразу - очень много сложный запросов м объемы информации.
Было бы интересно знать, как устроена лента в VK

Comment: > очень много сложный запросов м объемы информации

Например? У меня, например, в mysql хранится в каждый момент времени от 2 до 3 миллионов статей, не считая десятков вспомогательных и связанных с ними таблиц. Основные поисковые задачи выполняет Sphinx, и не сказал бы, что запросы простые. Всё живо, активно шевелится и менять технологии пока повода не вижу.

Comment: http://profyclub.ru/docs/103 Примерно в середине описывают как они делали ленту новостей, ищи по фразе "Как функционирует страничка новостей". Вкраце -- эта задача НАМНОГО труднее чем кажется.

Comment: > очень много сложный запросов м объемы информации.

Ну это от движка БД зависит, конечно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для таких целей, как мне кажется, неплохо подойдет что-то из разряда графовых бд, самое поддерживаемое и популярное решение - [neo4j](http://www.neo4j.org/). Ходят слухи, что графовые бд очень хороши как с точки зрения производительности, так и с точки зрения написания запросов на выборки.

в vk говорят, что они используют в роле хранилища свои нереляционные бд и даже не так давно выгружали основную в open source (анонс можно искать на хабре)

Answer (score -3):

А обновление статей, добавление в реальном времени, происходит с помощью jQuery, Ajax, и функции append

Работают то они с MySQL базой.

Comment: @CharCoder, конкретно у vk своя собственная БД, помщмте по kdb.